# How to Get Value of Another Column in The Same Table to Become as a Reference

Tags: mysql

I want to generate one column named `port_filled` in `m_olt_port` using `COUNT()` where the row's values are generated based on the other table total value which is `m_odp` and have the same id reference. What i expect to achieve is like this text table below:

**`m_olt_port`**

```
╔═════════════╦═════════════╗
║ id_olt_port ║ port_filled ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1           ║ 2           ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 2           ║ 3           ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 3           ║ 5           ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 4           ║ 0           ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 5           ║ 0           ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 6           ║ 0           ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 7           ║ 0           ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 8           ║ 0           ║
╚═════════════╩═════════════╝
```

The `m_odp` itself is like this:

**`m_odp`**

```
╔════════╦═════════════╗
║ id_odp ║ id_olt_port ║
╠════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1      ║ 1           ║
╠════════╬═════════════╣
║ 2      ║ 1           ║
╠════════╬═════════════╣
║ 3      ║ 2           ║
╠════════╬═════════════╣
║ 4      ║ 2           ║
╠════════╬═════════════╣
║ 5      ║ 2           ║
╠════════╬═════════════╣
║ 6      ║ 3           ║
╠════════╬═════════════╣
║ 7      ║ 3           ║
╠════════╬═════════════╣
║ 8      ║ 3           ║
╠════════╬═════════════╣
║ 9      ║ 3           ║
╠════════╬═════════════╣
║ 10     ║ 3           ║
╚════════╩═════════════╝
```

The code I've tried is by using nested `SELECT` to get value from `m_odp` table to be shown in `m_olt_port` table, like this:

```
SELECT 
m_olt_port.*, 

(SELECT COUNT(m_odp.id_olt_port) 
FROM m_odp 
JOIN m_olt_port ON m_odp.id_olt_port = m_olt_port.id_olt_port
WHERE m_odp.id_olt_port = 3) AS port_filled,

m_olt_port.id_olt_port

FROM m_olt_port
```

But the problem is, I can't get the right value to fill inside `WHERE` condition which is make the result is wrong just like this:

**`Result`**

```
╔═════════════╦═════════════╗
║ id_olt_port ║ port_filled ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1           ║ 5           ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 2           ║ 5           ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 3           ║ 5           ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 4           ║ 5           ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 5           ║ 5           ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 6           ║ 5           ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 7           ║ 5           ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 8           ║ 5           ║
╚═════════════╩═════════════╝
```

I think the problem is in the nested where condition which is `WHERE m_odp.id_olt_port = 3`.   I think if that 3 is dynamically change matching the `id_olt_port`'s value between `m_olt_port` and `m_odp`, it will generate different row based on their total count.

But how can I achieve this?

Comment: You've jumped right into the problem without giving us a background.  What is the input table, what is the output, and what is the logic behind that output?

Comment: Provide tables CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts instead of table-formed content. Explain the relation between source and result - column by column.

Comment: Ok im sorry, I thought table-formed content would be sufficient to explain the relation.. i'll input this into the post

Comment: For to obtain `m_olt_port` data from `m_odp` data use trivial `SELECT id_olt_port, COUNT(*) FROM m_odp GROUP BY id_olt_port;`.

Comment: @Akina Yeah i think group by is the right function to do this. Should I use Join too? I'll tell you after I done modifying the code

Comment: @Akina i use this query based on your suggestion : 

`
SELECT 
m_olt_port.*, 
(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM m_odp 
GROUP BY id_olt_port) AS port_filled
FROM m_olt_port
`

But it returns _subquery returned more than 1 row_

Comment: @Akina yeah it return 3 column from `m_odp` thanks, but i expect the result is looked like the new modified table on the post above. If there is no primary id available from `m_olt_port` inside `m_odp`, then it will show 0

Comment: *it return 3 column* I don't understand what you do really - but it is not related to one I have recommended.

Comment: @Akina Because, look at the id on my second table-formed content named `m_odp`, they are only referring to 3 `id_olt_port`  id in `m_olt_port`, so yeah it's true using `GROUP BY` will only result 3 row if we do inside `m_odp` table. But what I want the result is looked like just the first table I created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE m_odp (id_odp INT, id_olt_port INT);
> INSERT INTO m_odp VALUES
> (1,1),
> (2,1),
> (3,2),
> (4,2),
> (5,2),
> (6,3),
> (7,3),
> (8,3),
> (9,3),
> (10,3);
> SELECT * FROM m_odp;
> ```
>
> ```
> id_odp | id_olt_port
> -----: | ----------:
>      1 |           1
>      2 |           1
>      3 |           2
>      4 |           2
>      5 |           2
>      6 |           3
>      7 |           3
>      8 |           3
>      9 |           3
>     10 |           3
> ```

> ```
> SELECT id_olt_port, COUNT(*) FROM m_odp GROUP BY id_olt_port;
> ```
>
> ```
> id_olt_port | COUNT(*)
> ----------: | -------:
>           1 |        2
>           2 |        3
>           3 |        5
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b7dc55aac187165bb3e00df785a1bd7f)*

It is not possible to obtain the result shown - there is no source data in `m_odp` table which provided the existence of ports ##4-8.

Comment: Ahh, there you go.. So basically there are no way to display the rest number (4-8) with 0 (zero) result without existing values in `m_odp` ??

Comment: @MuhammadFaisal *So basically there are no way to display the rest number (4-8) with 0 (zero) result without existing values in m_odp ??* Basically - no way to understand what upper limit is to be set - is it to be 8, or, for example, 14, or 23? Server CANNOT to return the information which is absent.

Comment: Hmm alright then, I think I should find another approach..
Thanks a lot!